# Passing pandas DataFrame by reference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pass-by-reference, immutability

My question is regarding immutability of pandas DataFrame when it is passed by reference. Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

def foo(df1, df2):

    df1['B'] = 1
    df1 = df1.join(df2['C'], how='inner')

    return()

def main(argv = None):

    # Create DataFrames. 
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(range(0,10,2), columns=['A'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(range(1,11,2), columns=['C'])

    foo(df1, df2)    # Pass df1 and df2 by reference.

    print df1

    return(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = main()
    sys.exit(status)
```

The output is

```
   A  B  
0  0  1
1  2  1
2  4  1
3  6  1
4  8  1
```

and not

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  2  1  3
2  4  1  5
3  6  1  7
4  8  1  9
```

In fact, if foo is defined as

```
def foo(df1, df2):

    df1 = df1.join(df2['C'], how='inner')
    df1['B'] = 1

    return()
```

(i.e. the "join" statement before the other statement) then the output is simply

```
   A    
0  0 
1  2 
2  4 
3  6 
4  8
```

I'm intrigued as to why this is the case. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: btw, return isn't a function, it's just a statement, so you don't need the brackets after it.

Comment: [This](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) is the best discussion of how Python names work that I know of. Once you understand that, you will understand this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @chthonicdaemon !

Answer (score 10):

The issue is because of this line:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2['C'], how='inner')
```

`df1.join(df2['C'], how='inner')` returns a new dataframe. After this line, `df1` no longer refers to the same dataframe as the argument, but a new one, because it's been reassigned to the new result. The first dataframe continues to exist, unmodified. This isn't really a pandas issue, just the general way python, and most other languages, work.

Some pandas functions have an `inplace` argument, which would do what you want, however the join operation doesn't. If you need to modify a dataframe, you'll have to return this new one instead and reassign it outside the function.

Comment: Thanks @Jezzamon. It makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

Python doesn't have pass by value vs. pass by reference - there are just [bindings from names to objects](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

If you change your function to

```
def foo(df1, df2):

    res = df1.join(df2['C'], how='inner')
    res['B'] = 1

    return res
```

Then `df1`, `df2`, in the function, are bound to the objects you sent. The result of the `join`, which is a new object in this case, is bound to the name `res`. You can manipulate it, and return it, without affecting any of the other objects or bindings.

In your calling code, you could just write

```
print foo(df1, df2)
```