# How to replace a Dataframe with another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am passing in a single dataframe for performing various other data cleansing processes. While doing so, one of the process I am unable to complete without having another dataframe.

```
data= {'ID':[1,2], '2020-11-01' :[10,15], '2020-11-02':[43,35]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df1.head()


    ID  2020-11-01  2020-11-02
0   1   10  43
1   2   15  35
```

I would need to convert those dates as rows so used melt

```
df2 = df1.melt(id_vars = ["ID"], var_name = "ReportDate", value_name= "Units")
df2.head()

    ID  ReportDate  Units
0   1   2020-11-01  10
1   2   2020-11-01  15
2   1   2020-11-02  43
3   2   2020-11-02  35
```

Now I need to drop everything from df1 and need to capture the df2 details to df1.

I tried to drop all columns from df1(using inplace=True) and then do

```
df1["ID"] = df2["ID"]
df1["ReportDate"] = df2["ReportDate"]
df1["Units] = df2[Units]
df1.head()

    ID  ReportDate  Units
0   1   2020-11-01  10
1   2   2020-11-01  15
```

But I ended up with only 2 rows since the previous shape of df1 was 2x3

I need my output to look like

```
df1.head()

    ID  ReportDate  Units
0   1   2020-11-01  10
1   2   2020-11-01  15
2   1   2020-11-02  43
3   2   2020-11-02  35
```

How do I get df1 to have all the contents of df2?

Comment: What should your final df1 look like? Please show as if you called `f1.head()` as you show the earlier stages.

Comment: Why does `df1 = df2` not satisfy your requirements? or `import copy 
df1 = copy.deepcopy(df2)`

Comment: @noah I have updated with head and how my result should look like

Comment: @piterbarg because that doesnt update the existing df1, it create a new dataframe object and am unable to pass on my class. I do all my changes to only one dataframe using inplace=true, I haven't done copy part, lemme try that

Comment: I see. Here is what seems to be a relevant discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783570/passing-pandas-dataframe-by-reference/39783626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the objective is to assign the content of `df2` to `df1` while making sure that `id(df1)` does not change through this operation. This seems to do it but probably not the most elegant way. Main difference from what you tried is dropping the index as well as columns

```
df1.drop(df1.columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
df1.drop(df1.index,  inplace=True)
df1[df2.columns] = df2[df2.columns]
df1.head()
```

it maybe better design to have a function `process_data` that can be used as such

```
df1 = process_data(df1)
```

then df1 can be changed inside your function but when returned from the function it is assigned to the same variable

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know I could drop the indexes as well, thank you. I will try to have a function incorporated in the existing design.